# Como faço para selecionar todas as ocorrências de uma seleção no Visual Studio Code da mesma maneira que faço no Sublime Text?

Tags: visual-studio-code

No sublime Text, é possível selecionar todas as ocorrências de uma seleção e editá-las ao mesmo tempo. Para fazer isso basta eu apertar ALT+F3 depois de fazer a seleção, como no exemplo abaixo:

[image: Seleção de várias ocorrências no Sublime Text]

<sub>No exemplo, é selecionado `</a></li>` e, em seguida, todas as ocorrências iguais são selecionadas</sub>

Eu gostaria de saber como fazer isso no Visual Studio Code. Alguém poderia me explicar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No Visual Studio Code, o atalho equivalente ao <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> do Sublime Text seria o <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>.

Você seleciona o texto desejado e, em seguida, aperta <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>.

Answer (score -2):

Você pode também selecionar uma palavra e depois ir clicando CTRL+D pra ir selecionando a mesma palavra uma a uma.